# is it possible to get a single column output from a multi-column Query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using a QUERY function in Google Sheets. I have a named data range ("Contributions" in table on another sheet) that consists of many columns, but I'm only concerned with two of them. For simplicity sake, it looks something like this:

[image: sample table]

I have another table that contains the unique set of names (e.g.: "Fred", "Ginger", etc. each only once) and I want to extract the level # (column B) from the above table to insert the most recent (largest number) in this second table.

Right now, my query looks like this:

```
=QUERY(Contributions, "select B,C where C='"&A5&"' order by B desc limit 1",1)
```

The problem is, that it outputs both B & C data - e.g.:

```
11 Fred
```

But since I already have the name (in column A of this other table) I only want it to output the value from B - e.g.:

```
11
```

Is there a way to output only a subset (in this case 1 of 2) of the columns of output based on a directive within the query itself (as opposed to doing post-processing of the results)?

Comment: Also I don't think you need query for that. A vlookup would do the work.

Comment: Regarding 1st response: Are you saying I can place a condition on 'C' but only select on 'B' ? i.e.: "select B where C = ..." ?

Comment: @Marios: I guess I wasn't completely clear. The unique list of names used to drive the query is on one sheet, the data (example shown) is on another sheet. On the first sheet, I want to extract the last value of column B [on second sheet] where column C [on second sheet] matches the value in column A [on first sheet]. I don't believe vlookup will do this as vlookup will only search against the first column in the range, but I want to search against the 2nd column in the range (range = B1:C)

Comment: @Calculuswhiz: I'll be darned - it does work. I was assuming that I needed to include C in the selection since I wanted to use it as a constraint - but apparently I don't need to. YAY - Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to mark a comment as a solution - or should I "answer" the question myself and try to give credit where it's due?

Comment: @AdamStoller - nope, there is not. You can ask the commenter to do so, though. If they don't respond, feel free to post as an answer (please make it a community wiki as a courtesy to the person who provided help).

Comment: hopefully I succeeded - I assumed the wiki would be seen outside the context of the original question, so I included the basis of the question within the wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Outputting a Subset of Columns Used in Query**

In order to output only certain columns of a query result, the query only needs to *select* the columns to be displayed while the constraints / conditions may utilize *other* columns of data.

For example (as an answer to my own question) - I have a table like this:

[image]

I needed to get the data from the row with a name matching another cell (on another sheet) and with the latest (largest) number - but I only want to output the number part.

My initial attempt was:

```
=QUERY(Contributions, "select B,C where C='"&A5&"' order by B desc limit 1",1)
```

But that output both B & C where I only wanted B. The answer (thanks to @ Calculuswhiz) was to continue using C for the condition but only select on B:

```
=QUERY(Contributions, "select B where C='"&A5&"' order by B desc limit 1",1)
```